# how to query based on boolean attribute in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to query only objects from the database whose boolean attribute "in_season" returns true and its not working.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
validates :price, presence: true, numericality: true
validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer:    true }
validates :description, presence: true


def self.in_season
  where("in_season = ?", "true")
end
```

end

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @items = Item.in_season
end

end
```

I feel like everything is set up correctly and I'm not getting any errors, but my index page is blank because none of the items are being queried correctly.

Comment: You are asking about a boolean but passing a string for your comparison. where("in_season = ?", true) or where(in_season: true) should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the syntax. Your mistake is that you're passing a string `"true"`, whereas you want to pass boolean value `true`.

```
def self.in_season
  where(in_season: true)
end
```

It's more Railsy to use [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) for such needs:

```
scope :in_season, -> { where(in_season: true) }
```

Read more about scoping in [Rails Guides on scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).